# Tikz: edge with and without arrows in a style file

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

How can I write a style file so that I can have combined arrow and no arrow edges?

Here is a minimalist example. I would like to have a dashed line from O1 to A1 without an arrow.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    connected/.style={dashed}, %how can I change this line to make connected without arrow?
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [state](O1) at (0,0) {$O_1$};
\node[state](A1) at (2,0) {$A_1$};
\node[state](O2) at (4,0){$O_2$};
\path (O1) [connected] edge (A1);
\path (A1) edge (O2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example--MWE--which starts with `begin(document)` and finishes with `end(document)` as per the site rules. There should also be a preamble as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}`

Comment: you may try this `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\a{2.5}
\path[every node/.style={ellipse,draw,minimum width=.7 cm}] 
(0,0) node (O1) {$O_1$}
(\a,0) node (A1) {$A_1$}
(2*\a,0) node (O2) {$O_2$};
\draw[dashed] (O1)--(A1);
\draw[-latex] (A1)--(O2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Just followed your suggestion and modified my question. Please see above.

Comment: @BlackMild, just revised my question. I was thinking to use the style file again and again. Any idea to help me modifying my example? I just revised my question by providing a minimalist example.

Comment: @drbombe: First, you delete this `%-Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,`, and then use `\path[->] (A1) edge (O2);` in the last line of you code

Comment: @BlackMild It seems doesn't work. Because \node[sate] become undefined

Comment: here you are `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzset{
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    connected/.style={dashed},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [state](O1) at (0,0) {$O_1$};
\node[state](A1) at (2,0) {$A_1$};
\node[state](O2) at (4,0){$O_2$};
\path (O1) [connected] edge (A1);
\path[-latex] (A1) edge (O2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question

> How can one remove the arrows from an edge?

is

> Add `-` to the options of the edge/style.

So I added a `-` to the `connected` style to obtain

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex,dashed},
    connected/.style={dashed,-},% <- add a - to suppress the arrows
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,nodes={state},-Latex]
\path (0,0) node (O1)   {$O_1$}  
    ++ (2,0) node(A1) {$A_1$}++ (2,0) node(O2) {$O_2$}
    (O1) edge[connected]  (A1) (A1) edge (O2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would write your MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes}
\tikzset{
     semithick,
                > = Latex,
     state/.style = {ellipse, draw, minimum width = 5mm},
bidirected/.style = {<->, dashed},  % not used in this MWE
 connected/.style = {dashed}, 
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state](O1) at (0,0) {$O_1$};
\node[state](A1) at (2,0) {$A_1$};
\node[state](O2) at (4,0){$O_2$};
\path   (O1) edge[connected] (A1)
      % (O1) edge[dashed] (A1)  % gives the same result as above line
                                % using it you not need style "connected"  
        (A1) edge[->] (O2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: I remove all not used libraries and defined styles  except `bidirected`.

[image]